# How to interpret battery health from powercfg results

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

While I am fairly experienced with desktop DIY repair, I have found myself stuck when dealing with my laptop.

I am using a Lenovo Legion Y530-15ICH-1060 and after a recent flight the battery has stopped functioning, meaning I can only use the laptop while it is plugged in. I doubt the flight had anything to do with it since it was in my carry-on luggage, however I thought I'd mention the coincidence.

The battery is permanently stuck at 90% when plugged in. However, the laptop cannot start without being plugged in and immediately powers off when I pull the wall power while it is running.

My main question would be: is there a way to ascertain whether this is a hardware issue (therefore I should purchase a new battery) or if it is an OS / software issue that is reading the battery incorrectly.

I have included the results of `powercfg /batteryreport` below. I am not experienced enough to evaluate that data that it generated so I've added it in case it offers help when answering.

[Battery specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bxRC.png)

[Recent Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNGg5.png)

[Battery Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kim88.png)

[Usage History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McDRy.png)

[Battery capacity history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elKCx.png)

[Battery life estimates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ZZT.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"However, the laptop cannot start without being plugged in and immediately powers off when I pull the wall power while it is running."

The system seems to detect the battery, so I don't think it is a connection issue (which would be really rare anyway). The battery is almost certainly the cause and it should be replaced.

You can double check that it is not an Operating System issue by going into the BIOS screen and pulling the plug since. I also presume it won't turn on without wired power, which again would indicate the battery is at fault.

Comment: Thanks, this does make sense. I will be getting a new battery instead of trying to mess around with my current one.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again after you offered insight to my question, but something strange has happened and I was wondering if you could offer more insight. In a turn of events my battery has started working again! I didn't do anything to fix it, however it just started running from battery power again today after having had issues for about a month. Any idea what that could mean?